# Is there a numpy function for generating sequences similar to R's seq function?

Tags: python, numpy

In R, you can create a sequence by specifying the start point, end point, and desired length of output

```
seq(1, 1.5, length.out=10)
# [1] 1.000000 1.055556 1.111111 1.166667 1.222222 1.277778 1.333333 1.388889 1.444444 1.500000
```

In Python, you can use the `numpy`  `arange` function in a similar way, but there's no easy way to specify the output length. The best I can come up with:

```
np.append(np.arange(1, 1.5, step = (1.5-1)/9), 1.5)
# array([ 1.        ,  1.05555556,  1.11111111,  1.16666667,  1.22222222, 1.27777778,  1.33333333,  1.38888889,  1.44444444,  1.5       ])
```

Is there a cleaner way to perform this operation?

Comment: have you tried `numpy.linspace`?

Comment: The [`numpy.arange` documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) helpfully mentions [`numpy.linspace`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html#numpy.linspace) in the "See also" section. Look at that section whenever you're looking for a function that does something similar or related to a function you know about.

Comment: @cel No I have not, looks like that answers my question!

Comment: You can also use [`np.r_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html)'s slice indexing syntax with an imaginary number as the "step" parameter, e.g. `np.r_[1:1.5:10j]`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes! An easy way to do this will be using `numpy.linspace`

> [Numpy Docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html#numpy.linspace)
>
> numpy.linspace(start, stop, num=50, endpoint=True, retstep=False, dtype=None)
>
> Return evenly spaced numbers over a specified interval.
>   Returns num evenly spaced samples, calculated over the interval [start, stop].
>   The endpoint of the interval can optionally be excluded.

Example:

```
[In 1] np.linspace(start=0, stop=50, num=5)

[Out 1] array([  0. ,  12.5,  25. ,  37.5,  50. ])
```

Notice that the distance between the start and stop values is evenly spaced, i.e. evenly divided by `num=5`.

For those having problems installing numpy (a problem less common these days), you might look in to using [anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/) (or [miniconda](https://conda.io/miniconda.html)), or some other similar distribution.

Comment: How about integers only?

Comment: Depends on how you want to slice it. One way (if you're happy to simply truncate the output) is to cast to integer like so:

np.linspace(start=0, stop=50, num=5).astype(np.int32)

Otherwise, you can specify a range that will output integers, and then cast those to int.

Comment: Thanks, casting doesn't seem to be necessary `np.array(range(0,5)).dtype` returns `dtype('int64')`.

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative (and for those interested), if one wanted the functionality of `seq(start, end, by, length.out)` from R, the following function provides the full functionality.

```
def seq(start, end, by = None, length_out = None):
    len_provided = True if (length_out is not None) else False
    by_provided = True if (by is not None) else False
    if (not by_provided) & (not len_provided):
        raise ValueError('At least by or length_out must be provided')
    width = end - start
    eps = pow(10.0, -14)
    if by_provided:
        if (abs(by) < eps):
            raise ValueError('by must be non-zero.')
    #Switch direction in case in start and end seems to have been switched (use sign of by to decide this behaviour)
        if start > end and by > 0:
            e = start
            start = end
            end = e
        elif start < end and by < 0:
            e = end
            end = start
            start = e
        absby = abs(by)
        if absby - width < eps: 
            length_out = int(width / absby)
        else: 
            #by is too great, we assume by is actually length_out
            length_out = int(by)
            by = width / (by - 1)
    else:
        length_out = int(length_out)
        by = width / (length_out - 1) 
    out = [float(start)]*length_out
    for i in range(1, length_out):
        out[i] += by * i
    if abs(start + by * length_out - end) < eps:
        out.append(end)
    return out
```

This function is a bit slower than `numpy.linspace` (which is roughly 4x-5x faster), but using [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) the speed we can obtain a function that is about 2x as fast as `np.linspace` while keeping the syntax from R.

```
from numba import jit
@jit(nopython = True, fastmath = True)
def seq(start, end, by = None, length_out = None):
    [function body]
```

And we can execute this just like we would in R.

```
seq(0, 5, 0.3)
#out: [3.0, 3.3, 3.6, 3.9, 4.2, 4.5, 4.8]
```

In the implementation above it also allows (somewhat) for swaps between 'by' and 'length_out'

```
seq(0, 5, 10)
#out: [0.0,
 0.5555555555555556,
 1.1111111111111112,
 1.6666666666666667,
 2.2222222222222223,
 2.7777777777777777,
 3.3333333333333335,
 3.8888888888888893,
 4.444444444444445,
 5.0]
```

## Benchmarks:

```
%timeit -r 100 py_seq(0.5, 1, 1000) #Python no jit
133 µs ± 20.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 100 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit -r 100 seq(0.5, 1, 1000) #adding @jit(nopython = True, fastmath = True) prior to function definition
20.1 µs ± 2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 100 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit -r 100 linspace(0.5, 1, 1000)
46.2 µs ± 6.11 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 100 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can find more examples [here](http://mathesaurus.sourceforge.net/r-numpy.html), it contains a lot of R functions with numpy package.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

@PaulG's answer is very good to generate series of floating point numbers. In case you are looking for the R equivalent of `1:5` to create a numpy vector containing 5 integer elements, use:

```
a = np.array(range(0,5))
a
# array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

a.dtype
# dtype('int64')
```

In contrast to R vectors, Python lists and numpy arrays are zero indexed. In general you will use `np.array(range(n))` which returns values from `0` to `n-1`.